# TypeScript define variable type when getting value implicitly

Tags: typescript

If I do something like this in javascript

```
const { peer, users, ...otherProps } = props;
```

How do I do the same in TypeScript to be able to define the types that those variables will have?

Comment: Typescript knows what the type is. You don't have to do anything at all

Answer (score 2):

You can either type `props`:

```
interface TypeOfProps {
    peer: string;
    users: number;
    randomProp: string;
}
const props: TypeOfProps = {
    peer: "peer",
    users: 5,
    randomProp: "hah"
}
const { peer, users, ...otherProps } = props;
```

Or the spread object:

```
const { peer, users, ...otherProps}: TypeOfProps = props;
```

Both will correctly infer the types of `peer`, `users` and `otherProps`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to destruct you object with types,

1 :

```
const { peer, users }: { peer: string; users: Array<any> } = props
```

2 : Or you can create a type or interface for that data:

```
 interface Data {
  peer: string
  users: Array<any>
}
```

then use it :

```
const data: Data = props
```